# CollectionProxy returns nil when creating a new object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model with a has_many relationship that's built through nested forms:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :properties
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :properties, allow_destroy: true

  def billing_address
    debugger
    properties.find_by(billing_address: true)
  end
end
```

Overall, the relationship and nested form works. However, if I call the method `billing_address` during creation, then it returns nil, even if there is a nested property with billing_address set to true. I experimented with this in debugger, and it seems that calling `properties.find_by` or `properties.where` during creation always results in nil, even if the parameters match a real object.

When I type `properties` into debugger, I get results like this, which clearly show that there is a property with billing_address set to true:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [#<User::Property id: nil, address: "1111 E 1st", city: "Austin", state: "TX", zip_code: "11111", phone_number: "11111111111", user_id: nil, primary: true, billing_address: true, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>]>
```

So why can't I find it with a query such as `properties.find_by(billing_address: true)`? Is there another approach to getting at this data?

Answer (score 0):

`find_by` and `where` search the database (via SQL queries) and at the time you are checking, the records have not been saved, so they cannot be found there. I know of no way to "look up" the proxies, but if you provide some more information about the context in which you're trying to access them, I might have some ideas.

Comment: I'm accessing them during a validation call. It's in the model layer, so I don't have direct access to the params. Any other details that might help?

Comment: Sharing the validation code that's making the call might help.

Comment: This is the line that's throwing the error: `BraintreeRails::Customer.create!(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name, email: email, phone: billing_address.phone_number)`

Comment: That's within a validation? In any event, have your tried printing out `self` at that point?

Comment: I know, weird validation. (Basically, I'm confirming that Braintree can work with the user submitted data. If it can't, we rollback and give the user a validation error.) Anyway, `self` returns the user model as expected. `self.properties` returns the same collection proxy I show in the post. I get the sinking feeling that I'm going to have dig directly into the collection proxy and extract the property myself. There's no rails magic here, is there?

Comment: I don't think there's anything unnatural about accessing `properties` from the collection proxy, since it hasn't been saved yet. What's your concern? The intent of the proxy is to act like the "real thing" until the "real thing" (i.e. backed by the database) exists.